# Prompt in Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to make my sql interactive. First I want to display the list of items and then want to accept choice from user and display the result as per selection.

But when I try it, I am getting selection prompt before displaying the list.

Can anybody help me out?

I want OUTPUT LIKE THIS :-

LIST OF COUNTRIES :
(am getting this list by calling a procedure )

NO.     NAME

1. CANADA
2. US
3. UK
4. INDIA
5. JAPAN
6. CHINA

CHOOSE COUNTRY TO BE REPLACED :     (this will be saved in variable , say var1)

NO.     NAME

1. CANADA
2. US
3. UK
4. INDIA
5. JAPAN
6. CHINA

CHOOSE COUNTRY TO BE REPLACED :     (this will be saved in variable , say var2)

After the values accepted , I want to replace var1 with var2

So now can anybody tell me exactly what i should do ?

Comment: What do you mean by selection prompt?

Comment: The correct answer (*if* there is a correct answer) is dependent on the environment where the user has to choose an option.

Comment: A stored procedure (written in PL/SQL) is not able to ask the user for input. Even the way how output (DBMS_OUTPUT) is generated, is rather peculiar and requires an environment that supports it. There is a ´PROMPT´ command in SQL*plus, which implements some commands and logic in addition to SQL and PL/SQL. Most of these commands are supported in SQL Developer as well.

Comment: SQL isn't suited for this kind of activity.

Comment: Although you can accept user input in SQL like tbone stated in his answer, you should not do it. If you want to do this you should write a program to handle all the logic to wrap around the database.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a SQLplus script that accepts user input.  Try setting up a batch file and use the "**accept** variable **prompt** message" approach.  Just be wary of sql injection attacks (this isnt a good approach to data entry btw).

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b12170/ch6.htm#CACHDBHG) for Oracle doc on communicating with user in SQLPlus.

Answer (score 0):

If your environment is command line, SQL*PLUS for example, you could use plus statements to get this done. I've done similar in a plain-jane .sql file, as a 5 minute band-aid.

PROMPT will basically echo text to the screen.
ACCEPT will allow you to accept user input.

To display your list of options, just run a simple select.

Once you've accepted your input, pass to procedure from there.